# Singleton LoggedUser class on Infrastructure Layer?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

I'am developing an multi-layered application that suport many application UI consumers, like WinForms and MVC.

First, i'am developing a UI Windows forms to consume that.

I have the falowing project structure:

```
Application.DataAccess      - IUserRepository....
Application.Busines         - IUserService, ICustomerService...
Application.Infrastructure  - Logging, Exception handling... (Cross-cutting.)
Application.Domain          - Entities, User, Customer...
Application.WindowsForms     - UI
```

Most of my busines methods need User that has requesting like AddNewCustomer(Customer c, User requestingUser)...

I always have to pass Logged User through my User Interface application to Busines layer or should create a Singleton class on
Cross-cutting layer and use that on all of my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best choice is to have your UI Application (Presentation Layer) track the currently logged-in user, and pass that to the business layer on each call that needs to be made. This is especially true because it is through the UI Application that users login, and typically also the UI Application that manages active user sessions.

Your services (Business Layer) should be stateless, and therefore should have no knowledge of any active or logged in users.